# Local MySQL 5.7 server crashed, due to which removed installation and re-installed still same error

Tags: mysql, docker

I had installed MySQL, I rebooted my VM (on Fedora 27) for some reason, I am facing below error, while I was trying to start mysql service.

`[ravibeli@localdomain ~]$ sudo service mysqld start`

```
Logs:
[sudo] password for ravibeli: 
Starting mysqld (via systemctl):  Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status mysqld.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

When I run 'journalctl -xe' below error message shown, and unable to fix it? what is the way to fix this issue on VM (Fedora 27)

```
[ravibeli@localdomain ~]$ journalctl  -xe
May 07 16:06:53 localdomain sudo[6971]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 07 16:06:53 localdomain audit[6971]: USER_START pid=6971 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:sess
May 07 16:06:53 localdomain systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: MySQL database server....
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysqld.service has begun starting up.
May 07 16:06:53 localdomain mysqld[8145]: chown: invalid user: ‘mysql:mysql’
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain audit[726]: USER_AVC pid=726 uid=81 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:system_dbusd_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='avc: 
                                         exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=81 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain mysqld[8145]: Initializing MySQL database:  2018-05-07T10:36:54.847676Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depre
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain mysqld[8145]: 2018-05-07T10:36:54.851156Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't change to run as user 'mysql' ;  Please check that the user
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain mysqld[8145]: 2018-05-07T10:36:54.851678Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain mysqld[8145]: [FAILED]
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: MySQL database server..
-- Subject: Unit mysqld.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysqld.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain audit[1]: SERVICE_START pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=mysqld comm="systemd
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain sudo[6971]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain audit[6971]: USER_END pid=6971 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:sessio
May 07 16:06:54 localdomain audit[6971]: CRED_DISP pid=6971 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcr
lines 1393-1422/1422
```

Comment: Does the `mysql` user and group exist?

Comment: yes. mysql group exists. [root@localdomain ravibeli]# `cut -d: -f1 /etc/group | grep mysql` this has listed mysql

Comment: Does the user also exist? `grep mysql /etc/passwd`

Comment: I verified user also exists `[ravibeli@localdomain measure-service]$ grep mysql /etc/passwd`
mysql:x:1001:1001::/home/mysql:/bin/bash

Comment: I just realised that the logs are truncated at the far right. Hence the error is incomplete. Can you update the question with the complete log?